# Powershell 5.1 prepending $line variable to the result before appending (>>) to .csv

Tags: powershell, merge, append, pipeline, powershell-5.0

In powershell 5.1, my `foreach` loop appends data from `myProgram` to `data.csv`, using the append syntax, (`>>`).  The code below successfully appends/writes the result of my `getData --query`   to the `data.csv` file.

I want/need a small change to the generation of `data.csv`;
I want/need the `$line` variable and "`/`" merged into the beginning of each line of `data.csv`.  How can this be solved?

**generation code (`data.csv`):**

```
foreach($line in Get-Content -Path .\Folders.txt){$scrpt = 'myProgram getData --query "select key from datatable where key =''$line'')" --resultformat=csv >> data.csv'; Invoke-Expression $scrpt `   
} `;
```

**Expected result (`data.csv`)**

```
$line/data
$line/data
$line/data
```

**Actual result (`data.csv`)**:

```
data
data
data
```

Comment: Does myProgram offer options for how/what data is returned?

Comment: --resultformat of myProgram supports .json and .csv

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making use of the `$_` concept in powershell.

```
foreach($line in Get-Content -Path .\Folders.txt){$scrpt = 'myProgram getData --query "select key from datatable where key =''$line'')" --resultformat=csv |foreach {$line+"/"+$_} >> data.csv'; Invoke-Expression $scrpt `   
} `;
```